# Where to store the current state data using angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing, angular-ui-router-extras

This issue is happening here. 
Plunker link -> https://run.plnkr.co/NMW85SbYq76ujSjV/

I need to store the current state data somewhere apart from local storage using angular js. I have a list of models(cards) in one angular page. And there are two tabs in each card. First tab is having only simple text but second tab is having one button. So when a user clicks on the button (which is present in the second tab) then it redirects to new state where we are showing the description of the current model.

Here one problem is there. When user is on first state (where all of the models are visible) then this user is free to select any tab from any model. So suppose, we have 10 models and user select tab 2 for model 2, 4, 5, and 9. So here the view is like model 1, 3, 6, 7, 8 and 10 will be showing the tab 1 content and rest of the models will be showing the tab 2 content. Now when he/she clicks on the button present in second tab(of any model) then it redirects to description of model state. And here is button to go back to previous state. When he/she clicks on this button then it redirects to models state but the it's showing tab 1 content in all of the models instead of previous selected tabs accordingly.

So how can i handle this situation. I want to show previous state when a user comes back fro description state to models state.

Please help me guys. Please click on the above link to get the implemented plunker sample. Any lead would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi! The plunkr is currently 500-ing, so I can't check, but please choose _one_ tag between [tag:angular] (v2/4/5) and [tag:angularjs] (v1). They are not synonyms.

Comment: Yaa.. i edited it. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: And i'll see what is happening in Plunker.

Comment: Please check this one.
https://run.plnkr.co/NMW85SbYq76ujSjV/#/models

Comment: You can use this link of the same pluker -> https://plnkr.co/edit/RRAiZlhj93KNe1y2SAi1?p=info

Thanks guys

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a service and move the "flag" variable to the JSON.
I have modified your plunker. Please check.

https://plnkr.co/edit/5k8hXbCIid4NonSL4Y9k?p=preview

```
var getData = {};

        getData.get = $http.get('template.json')
            .then(function(response) {
              console.log(response);
                return response.data;
            })

       return getData;   
});

myRouterApp.component('myModels', {
  templateUrl: 'models.html',
  controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$state','getModelSvc', function TrialCtrl($scope, $http, $state,getModelSvc) {
    $scope.models = [];
    console.log(getModelSvc);
  getModelSvc.get.then(function(data) {
          $scope.models = data.models;
              console.log($scope.models);
    })
```

Comment: it's working fine on the ui as expected... let me go through the code.. :)
Thank you very very much buddy :)
you made my day :)

Comment: here we are modifying html and json file too. Is there any method to write a service which can do the same thing without affecting other files.

Comment: You can move the service logic to a newfile say "service.js" and refer it in your HTML. But you have to inject the service in your controller and hence controller code will have to be changed. Also, since the "flag" variable tracks the state of the tabs, you have to have it in the service so that the value is reflected across controllers.

Comment: Okay... i'll try this :)

Comment: but the same thing we can do in the same file right?

Comment: Im not sure I understand. The plunker I gave has the service in the same file.

Comment: yaa.. that's true.. why do we need the same service in some different file?

Comment: you can always inject it. any reason why you removed the accepted answer  check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157169/discussion-between-shravan-jain-and-vijay-menon).